# How to generate a decimal number?

Tags: javascript

I have my function to randomly generate a number between 2 numbers. but i don't know how to get a decimal such as 5.5, 7.3, 8.2. This is what i have so far.

```js
        function getrandomnumber(min, max) 
        {
        return (min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random()))
        }
        var a=getrandomnumber(1,10)*100/1000;
        document.write(a);
```

Comment: Er... you're the one calling `floor`...

Comment: ok i took it out and it works, but how do i keep my values under 10 and to 1 decimal place

Comment: use `.toFixed(1)` javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

A proposal with a check. It prevents interger numbers.

```js
function getrandomnumber(min, max) {
    function f() {
        return Math.floor(min + (max - min + 1) * 10 * Math.random()) / 10;
    }
    var v = f();
    while (Math.floor(v) === v) {
        v = f();
    }
    return v;
}

var a = getrandomnumber(1,10);
document.write(a);
```

Comment: thnks but i only want decimals no whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your function to return the value without having to divide it afterwards, modify it like this:

```js
        function getrandomnumber(min, max) 
        {
        return (min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random()*10))/10
        }
        var a=getrandomnumber(1,10);
        document.write(a);
```

Comment: i need it so it only displays decimals no whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) example from MDN

```
    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
          return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    var a = getRandomArbitrary(1,10);
    document.write(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer breaking this into multiple functions for flexibility as:

```
function roundNumber(number, decimalPoints) {
    return Math.floor(number * Math.pow(10, decimalPoints)) / Math.pow(10, decimalPoints);
}

//Generates a random number between max and min and rounds it to two decimal places.
function generateNumber(min, max) {
    //Generate a random number between min and max
    var randomNumber = ((max - min) * Math.random()) + min;
    //Return a number rounded to a given number of decimal places
  return roundNumber(randomNumber, 1);
}

function generateRandomDecimal() {
  var result = generateNumber(1, 10);
  // until you get a decimal result, keep generating the random number.
  while (result % 1 === 0) {
      result = generateNumber(1, 10);
  }
  return result;
}

var a = generateRandomDecimal();
document.write(a);
```